# How to modify expo router unmatched route

Tags: expo, expo-router

Does anyone know how to modify the default expo unmatched route:

[image: image of error]

I want to modify the front but i don't know how

I try to found something in the expo docs but it didn't help me. Do someone know how to do it?

Comment: Could you share your routing code, routes, code details, etc?